# How far from the launch site was the recovery drone for the center core of the Falcon Heavy test flight?

Tags: spacex, falcon-heavy, droneship

How far out to sea was the recovery drone *Of Course I Still Love You* for the Falcon Heavy test flight?

In the future, if there's a Falcon Heavy night launch with a similar flight profile, I'm wondering if the boostback burn, and even perhaps the landing burn, of the center rocket would be visible. Even though the rocket would be quite a distance out to sea, rocket burns are substantially brighter than the night sky, so I'd like to get a rough idea of elevation and/or distance of the center core from the launch site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Falcon Heavy demo flight simulation on FlightClub.io](https://www.flightclub.io/result?code=FHD1) (produced before the launch with available public information) has the final downrange distance for the center core at 347km. I don't know how closely that reflects the actual placement of OCISLY, but it's a reasonable estimate.

Comment: Oh wow, excellent site! No way that 350km is visible from the launch site. Good to know.